# can't display java code on my html website page in a proper formatted way

Tags: java, html, web

I am new to website development so what I am doing is using 
 tag after each line of code to break the line and giving space in starting to make it as presentable as it is in eclipse but while displaying the entire code it shifts to left. There is no proper formatting. Please provide a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern html, we can put programmable lines in a tag called "code". This is how all the blogs and forums are reflecting the programs including Stackoverflow as well.

For better understanding please take a look, https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_code_tag.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your code in html `<code></code>` tags